# Django handle Annonymous users

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to implement anonymous writes to a board.

The information of the anonymous user (IP address and nickname) must be stored in the database.

Currently, I have a `User` model and an `Article` model like this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'), unique=True, null=True)

    etc...

class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("Author"), on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    etc....
```

I thought of several ways to implement the anonymous write feature.

1. For every anonymous user create `User` with just ip address and nickname and set foreign key to that user.

   ```
   class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
       TYPE_FIXED_USER = 0
       TYPE_ANONYMOUS = 1

       TYPE_CHOICES = (
           (TYPE_FIXED_USER, 'Fixed User'),
           (TYPE_ANONYMOUS, 'Annonymous'),
       )

       user_type = models.IntegerField(_('User type'), choices=UserType.TYPE_CHOICES)
   ```

   This looks like the easiest way, but I worry that it will create a lot of `User` and cause high load to the database.
2. Add `author_type`, `anon_author_ip`, `anon_author_nick` field to `Article`.

   ```
   class Article(models.Model):
       TYPE_FIXED_USER = 0
       TYPE_ANONYMOUS = 1

       TYPE_CHOICES = (
           (TYPE_FIXED_USER, 'Fixed User'),
           (TYPE_ANONYMOUS, 'Annonymous'),
       )

       author_type = models.IntegerField(_('Author type'), choices=UserType.TYPE_CHOICES)
   ```

   This seems OK, but searching articles by nickname will be difficult. If I am to search for user `'user1234'` I will have to look for `Article.objects.filter(user__nickname__contains='user1234')` and `Article.objects.filter(anon_author_nick__contains='user1234')` and join them.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: is nick_name is unique or can duplicate nick-name allowed ?

Comment: @Shakil not unique for anonymous, unique for registered users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first way is good than second, don't worry about DB population

Basically if you want to save the anonymous user, you has been decided to remove Sign Up section of you're site and still has saved Users, So you must have to act like fixed user and generate a random Username or NickName for it without password

I propose you to use this simple way and if you wanna to speed up you're DB you can use Redis

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, do not worry about the number of users in your database, but give each person (anonymous or not) their own User record.

If you do want to go with 1 record, the package `django-guardian` creates an anonymous user (because it needs an actual database User row for its configuration), you can read more about it here: https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html

Note that Django has something like an anonymous User, a User-like object with `is_authenticated=False`. Sometimes when working with Anonymous Users this gets confusing.